# Cordova Plugin Reference Error (Dropbox Sync)

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, cordova-plugins

i have made a new Cordova App for android with these commands:

> $ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
>    $ cordova platform add android

and it worked. Then i added the Dropboc Sync Plugin with

> cordova plugin add https://github.com/rossmartin/phonegap-dropbox-sync-android.git

but i can't access the JS vars.
i tried

```
try{

DropboxSync.checkLink(function() { // success
alert("ok");
    // User is already authenticated with Dropbox.
}, function() { // fail
alert("fail");
    // User is not authenticated with Dropbox.
});

DropboxSync.link();

}catch(e){alert(e);}
```

and the alert or the e in alert says:

> ReferenceError: DropboxSync is not defined

Did i forget something?

changed index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>




        <script>

    function dropbox_linked() { }
// Called from the onActivityResult method in the plugin when linking is successful.
function dropbox_onSyncStatusChange(status) { }
// Called by observer in the plugin when there's a change 
// to the status of background synchronization (download/upload).
// status is a string variable that will be 'sync' or 'none'.
function dropbox_fileChange() { }
// Called by observer in the plugin when a file is changed.




try{
DropboxSync.checkLink(function() { // success
alert("Hallo ok");
    // User is already authenticated with Dropbox.
}, function() { // fail
alert("Hallo fail");
    // User is not authenticated with Dropbox.
});

        alert("Hallo");
        DropboxSync.link();
        alert("Hallo2");

        }catch(e){alert(e);}

        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using window.DropboxSync and also don't forget to check if that is properly installed by checking the android.json (if you're using netbeans you can see it at the Files window under plugins folder.